# Convert System.List<string> to Java.Lang.String[]

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm busy writing a android application in mono with Visual Studio. I'm busy implementing the `ISectionIndexer` on my Custom Adapter.

I'm struggling to convert a `System.List<string>` to a `Java.Lang.String[]`. Don't even know if it is possible?!

Some sample code:

```
    private List<string> _sections;

    public Java.Lang.Object[] GetSections()
    {
        return this._sections.ToArray(); // Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Java.Lang.Object[]'

    }
```

Could someone please assist with the conversion - if possible?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really sure about android, but do you have `.ToArray()` method with your list ?

Comment: Maybe you can give us a sample of what you tried, it looks a bit strange...

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java/

Comment: @Habib: Hi, that does not work. It gives an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Java.Lang.Object[]'.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Waqas: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure how that conversion will do the trick?!

Comment: why are you using mono ?

Comment: perhaps try using a loop to create array's elements one-by-one

Comment: @Waqas: Jip that is exactly what I did ... not pretty, but it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of the following method to solve the problem, not pretty, but it works!

```
    public Java.Lang.Object[] GetSections()
    {            
        Java.Lang.String[] tmpObjCollection = new Java.Lang.String[this._sections.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this._sections.Count; i++)
        {
            tmpObjCollection[i] = new Java.Lang.String(this._sections[i]);
        }

        return tmpObjCollection;
    }
```

Comment: Dear Richard, java.lang.String is a static class in IVKM.net. Therefore cannot be declared or instatiated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public Java.Lang.Object[] GetSections()
{            
    return new Java.Util.ArrayList(this._sections).ToArray();
}
```